# Need of Concurrent_log_handler with both time based and size based file rotation for python

Tags: python, logging, handler

Concurrent_log_hanlder for multiple process logging to a single file in python logging is working fine. But its logging file rotation is only based on size of the file.  I was in need of a concurrent_log_handler which supports both time based and size based file rotation.

Python inbuilt logging provide support to time based rotation and size based rotation. And also we can write custom logging we can combine the both the features. But this customized logging handler doesn't support multi process logging to a single file.

For my case I was in need of multiple process logging handler with both size and time based file rotation.

Is there any python logging handler available.   I tried combining concurrent_log_handler with python logging inbuilt time based rotating handler . It doesn't work for me. Is there any solution available to solve my case.

Comment: Can you give some additional info? What is your expecting outcome? Some code snippet?

Comment: I'm the maintainer of CLH. There is a issue open for the feature of time based rotation, though it was framed as an either-or with size based rotation, not combining them. This feature has a PR open but it has some issues that haven't been resolved yet. But if we ever get this completed, maybe it could work for you.

https://github.com/Preston-Landers/concurrent-log-handler/issues/23

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid all the hassle of multi-process-file-handles by using the [QueueHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#queuehandler) and [QueueListener](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#queuelistener). The architecture is to have a dedicated logging process which uses any single-process Handler and having this process read log messages from a Queue that all other processes send their logs to via the QueueHandler. It's not particularly hard to setup following the examples in the linked documentation.